# Django - How do I show a user's group?

Tags: python, django

As you can see, I just want to show the group to which the user belongs.

[Screenshot of the problem.](https://i.ibb.co/MhhsbYJ/group.jpg)

**models.py**

How do I show my group in my profile information within the admin?

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    ERKEK = 'E'
    KADIN = 'K'
    OTHER = 'O'
    CINSIYET = ((ERKEK, 'ERKEK'), (KADIN, 'KADIN'), (OTHER, 'DİĞER'))

    PUBLIC = 'P'
    FOLLOWING = 'F'

    VISIBLE = ((PUBLIC, 'PUBLIC'), (FOLLOWING, 'FOLLOWING'))

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name = "Kullanıcı")
    new_group_name = models.ManyToManyField(Group, max_length=20, verbose_name="Grup", blank=True)
    telefon_numarasi = models.CharField(max_length=11, verbose_name="Telefon Numarası", blank=True)
    cinsiyet = models.CharField(max_length=1, default=3, choices=CINSIYET, verbose_name="Cinsiyet", blank=True)
    hakkinda = models.TextField(max_length=500, verbose_name="Hakkında", blank=True)
    dogum_tarihi = models.DateField(verbose_name="Doğum Tarihi", null=True, blank=True)
    profil_photo = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_to, verbose_name="Profil Resmi", default='profile_photo/user_default.png', null=True, blank=False)
    visible = models.CharField(choices=VISIBLE, max_length=1, default=1, verbose_name="Profil Görüntüsü")

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural='Kullanıcı Bilgileri'

    def get_full_name_or_username(self):
        if self.user.get_full_name():
            return self.user.get_full_name()
        return self.user.username

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s Profile"%(self.get_full_name_or_username())

def create_user_profile(instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)

post_save.connect(receiver=create_user_profile, sender=User)
```

**forms.py**

How do I show my group when I edit my profile information on the site?

```
class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ERKEK = 'E'
    KADIN = 'K'
    OTHER = 'O'
    CINSIYET = ((ERKEK, 'ERKEK'), (KADIN, 'KADIN'), (OTHER, 'DİĞER'))

    cinsiyet = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Select(choices=CINSIYET))
    new_group_name = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Group.objects.all(), required=True)
    hakkinda = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea, max_length=500, label='Hakkında', required=False)
    dogum_tarihi = forms.DateField(widget=DatePickerInput(), required=False)
    telefon_numarasi = forms.CharField(max_length=11, label='Telefon Numarası', required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'new_group_name', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'dogum_tarihi', 'telefon_numarasi', 'cinsiyet', 'hakkinda']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserProfileForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field in self.fields:
            self.fields[field].widget.attrs={'class':'form-control'}

        self.fields['hakkinda'].widget.attrs['rows']=10
        self.fields['hakkinda'].widget.attrs['cols']=10
```

Despite our research, I could not find a solution. Please, can you offer me a solution?

Comment: You have `model = User` in the `Meta`, should this be `model = UserProfile`?

Comment: @IainShelvington `model = UserProfile` not work.

Comment: `new_group_name` is not a field on the `User` model so it does not make sense to have it on a model form for the `User` model

Comment: I've updated the codes. How can I do it?